# CArray: unable to assign variable returned from CArray to non-reference variable

Tags: c++, data-structures, mfc

I have a structure that contain vector as below :

```
struct MY_STRUCT
{
    LONG lVariable;
    CString strVariable;
    BOOL bVariable;

    vector<MY_ANOTHER_STRUCT> vecAnotherStruct;
};
```

And also I have a CArray that used for storing **MY_STRUCT** data type :

```
CArray<MY_STRUCT> arMyStruct;
```

I'm able to add elements of **MY_STRUCT** type into **arMyStruct** and all the elements I added are shown properly in "watch" window.

Problem arise when I try to get element from CArray.

```
// This line gives access violation error message.
MY_STRUCT structVariable = arMyStruct[0]; 
// This line work correctly
MY_STRUCT& structVariable = arMyStruct[0];
```

Can anyone please point out why first line does not work?

**EDIT :**

Following are further details that I think might be useful to narrow down the problem :

I have a class that contain both the definition of **MY_STRUCT** and **arMyStruct** as follow

```
class MyClass
{
    struct MY_STRUCT
    {
        LONG lVariable;
        CString strVariable;
        BOOL bVariable;

        vector<MY_ANOTHER_STRUCT> vecAnotherStruct;
    };

    CArray<MY_STRUCT> arMyStruct;

    void function()
    {
         // This line gives access violation error message 
         // when trying to access from here
         MY_STRUCT structVariable = arMyStruct[0]; 
    }
};

void someFunction()
{
    MyClass myClass;
    MyClass::MY_STRUCT aStruct;
    // initialize structure and add some data to vector

    myClass.arMyStruct.Add(aStruct);

    // This line work fine
    // when trying to access from here
    MY_STRUCT structVariable = arMyStruct[0]; 

    // When trying to access CArray element from below function, 
    // gives access violation error message
    myClass.function();

}
```

Comment: The first line attempts to make an actual copy of the first element, whereas the second line effectively just takes a copy of the address of the first element.

So the problem may be in the copy...

Answer (score 0):

The first line doesn't work because you omitted the second parameter of CArray definition:

```
CArray<MyType, MyType> myArray;
```

That parameter defines (if I'm not wrong), how you get access to array elements. Omitting it, the compiler get the default:

```
CArray<MyType, MyType&> myArray;
```

That should be the reason why first does not work and the latter yes.

UPDATE:

I've tried your code and... it works if you do these corrections:

```
class MyClass{
public:
struct MY_ANOTHER_STRUCT
{
      float foo;
};
struct MY_STRUCT
{
    LONG lVariable;
    CString strVariable;
    BOOL bVariable;
    vector<MY_ANOTHER_STRUCT> vecAnotherStruct;
};
CArray<MY_STRUCT> arMyStruct;
void function()
{
     // This line gives access violation error message 
     // when trying to access from here
     MY_STRUCT structVariable = arMyStruct[0];
}
};


void someFunction()
{
MyClass myClass;
MyClass::MY_STRUCT aStruct;
// initialize structure and add some data to vector

myClass.arMyStruct.Add(aStruct);

// This line work fine
// when trying to access from here
MyClass::MY_STRUCT structVariable = myClass.arMyStruct[0];

// When trying to access CArray element from below function, 
// gives access violation error message
myClass.function();
}
```

Comment: I have try using CArray<MyType, MyType> myArray; and got same result

Comment: What's inside "My_Another_Struct"?

Comment: What's inside "My_Another_Struct" : sets of long, CString and BOOL

Comment: Did you mean to overload operator = for CArray?